# Are Messianics considered Avodah Zarah?

Tags: avodah-zarah

I know a similar question was asked about Christians, however I am talking about a case where a Jew that has become a Messianic and does not view Jesus as a God and still keeps Torah as well as Shabbat can be considered guilty of Avoda Zarah (i.e. worshiping foreign gods)?

Comment: To my knowledge, Messianic Jews are Christians (most are apostates, some not) but with "Jewishy flavors" added. The thing is, there's a disagreement if Christianity is considered direct Avodah Zara or the indirect Shituf, which is the worship of God along another being. As Messianics view Jesus as the messiah, they're rejecting the concept of the Jewish messiah which is one of the basics of faith. Further, many Messianics reject the concept of the Oral Tradition, which is also one of the basics of faith.

Comment: Only by Jews...